# reverse forking .. extracting a repo from another repo

Tags: git, github, git-fork

I have opened a repo on github, started coding after that i found my self building a Generic Application model for the projects in my domain, now i want to extract the application model from my repo to another repo.

i can fork the repo and remove the files related ,particularly, to my project, but i will be miss-using the "fork" operation.

And also this command

```
git merge origin/upstream
```

will reproduce my project specific files.

it sounds like a reverse forking .. how to implement that ?

Comment: it's not about subdirectories, i mean to remove specific files/changes to make a generalized copy of the repo.

Comment: If you also want to remove the history of those other files, then the problem can be reduced to moving everything you want to keep to a subdir and detaching that as a separate repo.